# Query to create a trending report on user site searches, MySQL and PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My subscription website features a library of thousands of resource materials, built on a MySQL database using PDO.

Users can access resources by major categories and sub categories.  If a user is looking for something very specific, they can search the library.

I am currently logging all subscriber searches to a table:

```
table - search_terms
primary_key (primary_key)
search_terms (tinytext)
time_stamp (timestamp)
```

How can I generate a list of the top searches that my subscribers are using?

I am looking for ideas on a database query that goes beyond simply counting the occurrence of single words, since I would like the phrases.  Sample data:

```
primary_key     search_terms                             time_stamp
1               what kind of chicken feed should I use   12:01:01 mm/dd/yy
2               what makes a good chicken feed           13:01:23 mm/dd/yy
3               when should I feed my chickens           09:23:15 mm/dd/yy
4               how to build a chicken house             18:29:10 mm/dd/yy
5               good breed for laying eggs               22:14:01 mm/dd/yy
6               best chicken feed                        01:10:00 mm/dd/yy
7               how do I get blue eggs                   18:42:48 mm/dd/yy
8               what do I do with a broody hen           etc etc
9               what is a broody hen                     etc etc
10              stop a hen being broody                  etc etc
```

If this were the sample data, the top searches would be:
'chicken feed' and 'broody hen'.

Comment: Count the phrases then? If you want a count of anything, count it. We can't see your code, your database, its structure, its data. How can anyone tell you what to do besides the only logical thing - count it. Now, how you'll do it - well, that's for you to solve. Good luck.

Comment: I don't understand how php code can be relevant to a database issue.  The database information was already included, one table with three fields.  I added some sample data and the desired results.

Comment: It wasn't included, you added it in the edit, and it's not formatted so.. let's see how many people will bother to read that. If you can't see why code or structures are needed to provide a solution to programming problem.. well, I guess I'll go download myself some telepathy. Got a good link maybe?

Comment: How do I format it?

Comment: Click edit, highlight the text, press the `{}` icon.

Comment: what your looking to do is very complex, I would start by adding another column that is filtered `search_terms` where you have removed `stop words`, you can then implement a very basic `GROUP BY` with a `COUNT`

Comment: I am using fulltext on MySQL 5.7 with MyISAM engine.  So I think stopwords are used by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Trends' tables have 2 columns:  Search terms and a search volume index.  Composing an index is beyond the scope of what I can show you without considerably more information, but I suspect a "count" table will suffice for your needs.

The table you included above provides some clarify, but it doesn't allow me to demonstrate the value of "counting" search terms.  Therefore, I provided my own sample database:

```
   primary_key       search_terms          time_stamp
1            1               beer 2017-07-01 13:07:31
2            2         white wine 2017-07-04 13:39:28
3            3            whiskey 2017-07-05 01:06:23
4            4  whiskey for gifts 2017-07-05 04:17:22
5            5  craft beer denver 2017-07-05 14:48:03
6            6               beer 2017-07-10 07:33:13
7            7         white wine 2017-07-14 02:13:00
8            8  pinot grigio wine 2017-08-22 03:16:18
9            9 whiskey from japan 2017-08-23 07:30:59
10          10    white wine rare 2017-08-01 15:03:25
11          11         white wine 2017-08-02 14:15:24
12          12  craft beer dallas 2017-08-02 22:03:44
13          13   new york whiskey 2017-08-03 05:45:09
14          14         white wine 2017-08-03 16:06:18
15          15  beer ipa michigan 2017-08-04 20:15:50
```

Note that the search terms "beer" and "white wine" are listed more than once.  We can call a simple search query that:

Returns all distinct (or unique) search terms.

Counts the occurrence of each search term.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT search_terms AS 'Unique Search Terms',
    COUNT(search_terms) AS 'Occurrence'
FROM search_terms
GROUP BY search_terms
ORDER BY Occurrence DESC
```

The resulting output is:

```
   Unique Search Terms Occurence
1           white wine         4
2                 beer         2
3              whiskey         1
4    whiskey for gifts         1
5    craft beer denver         1
6    pinot grigio wine         1
7   whiskey from japan         1
8      white wine rare         1
9    craft beer dallas         1
10    new york whiskey         1
11   beer ipa michigan         1
```

It appears the search term "white wine" is more popular than "beer," and "beer" is more popular than the other search terms.  This is, of course, a simplified example, but the same query should work on a much larger table.

**EDIT:** I see you have modified your requirements and wish to filter out stop words. As others have suggested, this is far more complex.  You could, however, define a list of stop words to remove upon arranging the results.  The query provided above can then be modified to strip out those words and display only relevant keywords.

As a final recommendation, you probably don't want a column to share the same name as its table ("search_terms" in this case). This can lead to confusion and problems down the road.

Comment: Thank you, I believe this is sufficient for my needs.  Although now I am interested in creating a search volume index. Is there a way to increase the complexity of the query so that it counts 'white wine' and 'wine white' as the same search term?  FYI - the above database structure is made up, along with the data.  Using the same name for the table and a field was just fast typing.

Comment: As previously commented, according to documentation stopwords filtering is included in natural language fulltext searches in MySQL 5.7 on MyISAM engine.  So I believe I have that part covered.

Comment: @Trialsman 'white wine' = 'wine white' can be accomplished, but it would require the creation of a more complicated function - especially complicated, if you increase your dimensions beyond 2 words.  E.g. "organic american chicken feed" = "american organic chicken feed" = "organic chicken feed american" = ..... 22 other combinations